# Can't open PDB in Oracle 12c R2 for Windows 10

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Recently installed Oracle 12cR2 on my Windows 10 laptop. I'm trying to open the sample ORCLPDB for use and get the error shown in the SQL*Plus screenshot. In my research, looks like others have encountered this issue but there hasn't been any conclusive solution. I've tried researching through videos, Oracle documentation and forums with no luck.

Here are the steps that I've taken.

[image: Screenshot of SQL*Plus as sys]

**Here are my tnsnames entries:**

```
LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )

ORCLPDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orclpdb)
    )
  )
```

**Here are my Listener file entries:**

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\app\OracleHomeUser1\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:D:\app\OracleHomeUser1\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr12.dll")
    )
    (SID_DESC = 
      (SID_NAME = ORCLPDB)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\app\OracleHomeUser1\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1)
    )  
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

**Note** The Oracle 12R2 is installed on Windows 10 Home edition version 1903. OS build is 18362.418.

Please help as I've been struggling for couple of weeks! Many thanks for your help!! :)

Here's the content of the alert_orcl file for the past 2 days:

```
rs in file D:\APP\ORACLEHOMEUSER1\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_j000_8292.trc:
2019-11-10T17:48:30.952951-05:00
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job "SYS"."ORA$AT_OS_OPT_SY_347"
ORA-20001: Statistics Advisor: Invalid task name for the current user
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 47207
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_ADVISOR", line 882
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_INTERNAL", line 20059
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_INTERNAL", line 22201
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 47197
2019-11-10T17:58:28.042968-05:00
Resize operation completed for file# 3, old size 655360K, new size 665600K
2019-11-10T17:58:30.685688-05:00
Errors in file D:\APP\ORACLEHOMEUSER1\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_j000_4476.trc:
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job "SYS"."ORA$AT_OS_OPT_SY_349"
ORA-20001: Statistics Advisor: Invalid task name for the current user
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 47207
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_ADVISOR", line 882
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_INTERNAL", line 20059
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_INTERNAL", line 22201
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 47197
2019-11-10T18:00:00.562652-05:00
Errors in file D:\APP\ORACLEHOMEUSER1\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_j000_13736.trc:
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job "APEX_050000"."ORACLE_APEX_WS_NOTIFICATIONS"
ORA-04063: package body "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET" has errors
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET"
ORA-06512: at "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET_API", line 4898
2019-11-10T18:08:33.989588-05:00
Errors in file D:\APP\ORACLEHOMEUSER1\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_j000_19036.trc:
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job "SYS"."ORA$AT_OS_OPT_SY_351"
ORA-20001: Statistics Advisor: Invalid task name for the current user
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 47207
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_ADVISOR", line 882
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_INTERNAL", line 20059
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_INTERNAL", line 22201
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 47197
2019-11-10T18:18:31.552426-05:00
Errors in file D:\APP\ORACLEHOMEUSER1\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_j000_18668.trc:
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job "SYS"."ORA$AT_OS_OPT_SY_353"
ORA-20001: Statistics Advisor: Invalid task name for the current user
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 47207
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_ADVISOR", line 882
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_INTERNAL", line 20059
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_INTERNAL", line 22201
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 47197
2019-11-10T18:28:33.035473-05:00
Errors in file D:\APP\ORACLEHOMEUSER1\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_j000_11084.trc:
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job "SYS"."ORA$AT_OS_OPT_SY_355"
ORA-20001: Statistics Advisor: Invalid task name for the current user
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 47207
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_ADVISOR", line 882
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_INTERNAL", line 20059
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_INTERNAL", line 22201
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 47197
2019-11-10T18:30:00.624114-05:00
Errors in file D:\APP\ORACLEHOMEUSER1\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_j000_5216.trc:
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job "APEX_050000"."ORACLE_APEX_WS_NOTIFICATIONS"
ORA-04063: package body "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET" has errors
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET"
ORA-06512: at "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET_API", line 4898
2019-11-10T18:38:34.705198-05:00
Errors in file D:\APP\ORACLEHOMEUSER1\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_j000_12012.trc:
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job "SYS"."ORA$AT_OS_OPT_SY_357"
ORA-20001: Statistics Advisor: Invalid task name for the current user
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 47207
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_ADVISOR", line 882
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_INTERNAL", line 20059
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_INTERNAL", line 22201
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 47197
2019-11-10T18:48:35.891078-05:00
Errors in file D:\APP\ORACLEHOMEUSER1\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_j000_2552.trc:
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job "SYS"."ORA$AT_OS_OPT_SY_359"
ORA-20001: Statistics Advisor: Invalid task name for the current user
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 47207
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_ADVISOR", line 882
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_INTERNAL", line 20059
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_INTERNAL", line 22201
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 47197
2019-11-10T21:51:18.519574-05:00
Warning: VKTM detected a forward time drift. 
Time drifts can result in unexpected behavior such as time-outs. 
Please see the VKTM trace file for more details:
D:\APP\ORACLEHOMEUSER1\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_vktm_10132.trc
2019-11-10T21:51:24.604745-05:00
Errors in file D:\APP\ORACLEHOMEUSER1\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_j000_16664.trc:
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job "APEX_050000"."ORACLE_APEX_WS_NOTIFICATIONS"
ORA-04063: package body "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET" has errors
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET"
ORA-06512: at "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET_API", line 4898
2019-11-10T21:51:37.564979-05:00
Thread 1 cannot allocate new log, sequence 12
Private strand flush not complete
  Current log# 2 seq# 11 mem# 0: D:\APP\ORACLEHOMEUSER1\ORADATA\ORCL\REDO02.LOG
2019-11-10T21:51:37.647758-05:00
Errors in file D:\APP\ORACLEHOMEUSER1\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_j001_16608.trc:
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job "SYS"."ORA$AT_OS_OPT_SY_361"
ORA-20001: Statistics Advisor: Invalid task name for the current user
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 47207
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_ADVISOR", line 882
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_INTERNAL", line 20059
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_INTERNAL", line 22201
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 47197
2019-11-10T21:51:40.643657-05:00
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 12 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 3 seq# 12 mem# 0: D:\APP\ORACLEHOMEUSER1\ORADATA\ORCL\REDO03.LOG
2019-11-10T22:00:00.764705-05:00
Errors in file D:\APP\ORACLEHOMEUSER1\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_j000_19288.trc:
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job "APEX_050000"."ORACLE_APEX_WS_NOTIFICATIONS"
ORA-04063: package body "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET" has errors
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET"
ORA-06512: at "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET_API", line 4898
2019-11-10T22:01:24.387425-05:00
Errors in file D:\APP\ORACLEHOMEUSER1\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_j000_12440.trc:
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job "SYS"."ORA$AT_OS_OPT_SY_363"
ORA-20001: Statistics Advisor: Invalid task name for the current user
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 47207
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_ADVISOR", line 882
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_INTERNAL", line 20059
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_INTERNAL", line 22201
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 47197
2019-11-10T23:24:02.204591-05:00
Warning: VKTM detected a forward time drift. 
Please see the VKTM trace file for more details:
D:\APP\ORACLEHOMEUSER1\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_vktm_10132.trc
2019-11-10T23:24:03.743617-05:00
Errors in file D:\APP\ORACLEHOMEUSER1\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_j001_19172.trc:
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job "APEX_050000"."ORACLE_APEX_WS_NOTIFICATIONS"
ORA-04063: package body "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET" has errors
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET"
ORA-06512: at "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET_API", line 4898
2019-11-10T23:24:07.893235-05:00
Errors in file D:\APP\ORACLEHOMEUSER1\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_j000_14616.trc:
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job "SYS"."ORA$AT_OS_OPT_SY_365"
ORA-20001: Statistics Advisor: Invalid task name for the current user
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 47207
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_ADVISOR", line 882
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_INTERNAL", line 20059
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_INTERNAL", line 22201
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 47197
2019-11-10T23:30:00.352162-05:00
Errors in file D:\APP\ORACLEHOMEUSER1\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_j000_15996.trc:
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job "APEX_050000"."ORACLE_APEX_WS_NOTIFICATIONS"
ORA-04063: package body "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET" has errors
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET"
ORA-06512: at "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET_API", line 4898
2019-11-10T23:34:07.321600-05:00
Errors in file D:\APP\ORACLEHOMEUSER1\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_j000_17628.trc:
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job "SYS"."ORA$AT_OS_OPT_SY_367"
ORA-20001: Statistics Advisor: Invalid task name for the current user
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 47207
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_ADVISOR", line 882
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_INTERNAL", line 20059
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_INTERNAL", line 22201
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 47197
2019-11-10T23:44:05.942664-05:00
Resize operation completed for file# 3, old size 665600K, new size 675840K
2019-11-10T23:44:07.250777-05:00
Errors in file D:\APP\ORACLEHOMEUSER1\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_j000_18984.trc:
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job "SYS"."ORA$AT_OS_OPT_SY_369"
ORA-20001: Statistics Advisor: Invalid task name for the current user
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 47207
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_ADVISOR", line 882
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_INTERNAL", line 20059
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_INTERNAL", line 22201
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 47197
2019-11-10T23:54:08.116856-05:00
Errors in file D:\APP\ORACLEHOMEUSER1\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_j000_17168.trc:
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job "SYS"."ORA$AT_OS_OPT_SY_371"
ORA-20001: Statistics Advisor: Invalid task name for the current user
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 47207
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_ADVISOR", line 882
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_INTERNAL", line 20059
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_INTERNAL", line 22201
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 47197
2019-11-11T00:00:00.491208-05:00
Errors in file D:\APP\ORACLEHOMEUSER1\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_j000_13364.trc:
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job "APEX_050000"."ORACLE_APEX_WS_NOTIFICATIONS"
ORA-04063: package body "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET" has errors
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET"
ORA-06512: at "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET_API", line 4898
2019-11-11T00:04:08.269812-05:00
TABLE SYS.WRI$_OPTSTAT_HISTHEAD_HISTORY: ADDED INTERVAL PARTITION SYS_P457 (43779) VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2019-11-12 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
TABLE SYS.WRI$_OPTSTAT_HISTGRM_HISTORY: ADDED INTERVAL PARTITION SYS_P460 (43779) VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2019-11-12 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
2019-11-11T00:04:10.242413-05:00
Errors in file D:\APP\ORACLEHOMEUSER1\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_j000_12576.trc:
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job "SYS"."ORA$AT_OS_OPT_SY_373"
ORA-20001: Statistics Advisor: Invalid task name for the current user
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 47207
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_ADVISOR", line 882
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_INTERNAL", line 20059
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_INTERNAL", line 22201
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 47197
2019-11-11T00:14:11.060275-05:00
Errors in file D:\APP\ORACLEHOMEUSER1\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_j000_17152.trc:
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job "SYS"."ORA$AT_OS_OPT_SY_375"
ORA-20001: Statistics Advisor: Invalid task name for the current user
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 47207
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_ADVISOR", line 882
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_INTERNAL", line 20059
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_INTERNAL", line 22201
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 47197
2019-11-11T00:24:11.498403-05:00
Errors in file D:\APP\ORACLEHOMEUSER1\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_j000_7156.trc:
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job "SYS"."ORA$AT_OS_OPT_SY_377"
ORA-20001: Statistics Advisor: Invalid task name for the current user
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 47207
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_ADVISOR", line 882
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_INTERNAL", line 20059
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_INTERNAL", line 22201
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 47197
2019-11-11T00:25:10.116868-05:00
TABLE SYS.WRP$_REPORTS_TIME_BANDS: ADDED INTERVAL PARTITION SYS_P461 (3601) VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2019-11-11 01:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
2019-11-11T00:30:00.608764-05:00
Errors in file D:\APP\ORACLEHOMEUSER1\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_j000_10260.trc:
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job "APEX_050000"."ORACLE_APEX_WS_NOTIFICATIONS"
ORA-04063: package body "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET" has errors
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET"
ORA-06512: at "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET_API", line 4898
2019-11-11T00:34:13.016562-05:00
Errors in file D:\APP\ORACLEHOMEUSER1\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_j000_11772.trc:
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job "SYS"."ORA$AT_OS_OPT_SY_379"
ORA-20001: Statistics Advisor: Invalid task name for the current user
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 47207
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_ADVISOR", line 882
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_INTERNAL", line 20059
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS_INTERNAL", line 22201
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 47197
2019-11-11T11:13:12.219241-05:00
Warning: VKTM detected a forward time drift. 
Please see the VKTM trace file for more details:
D:\APP\ORACLEHOMEUSER1\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_vktm_10132.trc
2019-11-11T11:13:12.937564-05:00
Closing scheduler window
Closing Resource Manager plan via scheduler window
Clearing Resource Manager CDB plan via parameter
2019-11-11T11:13:16.063522-05:00
Errors in file D:\APP\ORACLEHOMEUSER1\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_j002_8140.trc:
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job "APEX_050000"."ORACLE_APEX_WS_NOTIFICATIONS"
ORA-04063: package body "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET" has errors
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET"
ORA-06512: at "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET_API", line 4898
2019-11-11T11:13:59.803724-05:00
TABLE SYS.WRP$_REPORTS: ADDED INTERVAL PARTITION SYS_P462 (3602) VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2019-11-12 01:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
TABLE SYS.WRP$_REPORTS_DETAILS: ADDED INTERVAL PARTITION SYS_P463 (3602) VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2019-11-12 01:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
2019-11-11T11:30:00.266486-05:00
Errors in file D:\APP\ORACLEHOMEUSER1\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_j000_15252.trc:
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job "APEX_050000"."ORACLE_APEX_WS_NOTIFICATIONS"
ORA-04063: package body "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET" has errors
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET"
ORA-06512: at "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET_API", line 4898
```

Comment: Which edition of Windows 10 are you using? Is there any useful information in the Alert log? find it in `$ORACLE_BASE/diag/rdbms/<dbname_in_lower_case>/$ORACLE_SID/trace/
`. I'm afraid this is going to be something low-level which will require some expert diagnosis.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response!  The Oracle 12R2 is installed on Windows 10 Home edition version 1903. OS build is 18362.418.

Comment: Here's the alert log entry:

Comment: How do i attach the log file, please?

Comment: Pasted log snippet for the past two days in the question! Thanks in advance for helping!! 

Comment: Thanks, APC! Does that mean I need to upgrade to Windows Pro or Education at the very least? And then try to reinstall? i.e., what are my options? and what's Docker, please?

Answer (score 1):

> The Oracle 12R2 is installed on Windows 10 Home edition

Uh oh. The [Installation Guide says](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/ntdbi/operating-system-checklist-for-oracle-database-installation-on-microsoft-windows.html#GUID-E3991846-D2D7-4D71-9F8F-F90996F046B5) Oracle database server is only certified for Pro, Enterprise and Education editions. At the least there's a lot less information available about troubleshooting installations on Home edition.

> Does that mean I need to upgrade to Windows Pro or Education

Oracle database is an enterprise grade product and probably depends upon OS capabilities beyond those of Home edition. But I can't guarantee upgrading your OS will solve this problem. I use a Mac :)

So, what to do? Docker is a platform for deploying containers, which are cut-down virtual machines. Docker allows us to run [say Oracle 12c EE on Linux](https://hub.docker.com/_/oracle-database-enterprise-edition) without having to have a dual-boot PC. That's how I run an Oracle database on my Mac. But Docker's [not that straightforward on Win10 Home](https://forums.docker.com/t/installing-docker-on-windows-10-home/11722) either.

Therefore I think your quickest route to success would be to install [Oracle VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads). Make sure you also install the Extensions pack. Then you can download and run a vbox image. Oracle hosts a large number of them [on this page](https://www.oracle.com/downloads/developer-vm/community-downloads.html): choose the one most fitted to what you want to learn. This was the approach I used the last time I need to run an Oracle database on Windows.

Comment: Thank you very much for the guidance, APC! :) I'll try that. :)

Comment: But why would I want to have another OS on the machine when Oracle is going to run on Windows? Are you suggesting to use the VirtualBox to run windows Pro on windows Home?

Comment: *"Are you suggesting to use the VirtualBox to run windows Pro on windows Home?"* No. You still need a Windows Pro licence to legally run it on a VM, and if you had that obviously you'd just upgrade your PC.

Comment: I installed upgraded to Win 10 Pro, uninstalled Oracle 12cR2 and then reinstalled it. That fixed the problem - orcl plugggable databse is now READ WRITE instead of just MOUNTED!  :) Now I just need to figure out what happened to my orcl user. LOL!